# Controls html5 player

Tags: html, controls, bitmovin-player

Hiya people i was hoping for some help for no reason the controls on chrome do not appear but they do on mozilla and IEcrappycrap do you have any idea about what could do it , i'm using a 360VR player (Bitmovin) dunno if it could have a link but when i take off the bitmovin player embed in a div , the controls works ...

```
    <body onload="Onload()">

    <div id="background">
    <img id="bg" class="bg" src="http://slpubmedias.tf1.fr/test_nocache/test_jf/Orange/Orange2/Bg_m.jpg" style="position:absolute;"/>
    <img id="redirection" class="redi" onclick="Redirection()" src="http://slpubmedias.tf1.fr/test_nocache/test_jf/Orange/Orange2/btn_1.gif" style="cursor:pointer;position:absolute;"/>
    </div>
    <div id="container">
    <a href="javascript:;" onClick="Bandeau(1);" > <img id="bandeau_top" class="bandeau" src="http://slpubmedias.tf1.fr/test_nocache/test_jf/Orange/Orange2/Pub_haut_m.jpg" style="position:absolute;"/></a>
    <img id="Fleche_G" class="fleche" onclick="Left()" src="http://slpubmedias.tf1.fr/test_nocache/test_jf/Orange/Orange2/fleche_gauche_m.png" style="position:absolute;"/>
    <img id="Fleche_D" class="fleche" onclick="Right()"  src="http://slpubmedias.tf1.fr/test_nocache/test_jf/Orange/Orange2/fleche_droite_m.png" style="position:absolute;"/>
    <div class="content">
    <div class="player-wrapper">
    <div id="playerDiv">
//bitmovinplayerembed here
    </div>

    </div>
    </div>
    <iframe name="__bkframe" height="0" width="0" frameborder="0" style="display:none;position:absolute;clip:rect(0px 0px 0px 0px)" src="about:blank"></iframe> 

    <video id="video1"   controls preload="none" onclick="Stop()" src="http://slpubmedias.tf1.fr/test_nocache/test_jf/Orange/ours.mp4" style="position:absolute;"></video>
    <img id="Video_played" class="Video" src="http://slpubmedias.tf1.fr/test_nocache/test_jf/Orange/dark.gif" style="position:absolute;"/>

    <div id="Choix">
    <a href="javascript:;" onClick="Play(1);" > <img id="Vid_1"  src="http://slpubmedias.tf1.fr/test_nocache/test_jf/Orange/Orange2/Vignette1_produit1_m.jpg" style="position:absolute;"/></a>


    <a href="javascript:;" onClick="Play(2);" ><img id="Vid_2"  src="http://slpubmedias.tf1.fr/test_nocache/test_jf/Orange/Orange2/Vignette2_produit2_m.jpg" style="position:absolute;"/></a>


    <a href="javascript:;" onClick="Play(3);" ><img id="Vid_3"  src="http://slpubmedias.tf1.fr/test_nocache/test_jf/Orange/Orange2/Vignette3_film_m.jpg" style="position:absolute;"/></a>


    <a href="javascript:;" onClick="Play(4);" ><img id="Vid_4"  src="http://slpubmedias.tf1.fr/test_nocache/test_jf/Orange/Orange2/Vignette4_betisier_m.jpg" style="position:absolute;"/></a>


    <a href="javascript:;" onClick="Play360(360);" ><img id="Vid_5"  src="http://slpubmedias.tf1.fr/test_nocache/test_jf/Orange/Orange2/Vignette5_360_m.jpg" style="position:absolute;"/></a>

    <img id="text_video"  src="http://slpubmedias.tf1.fr/test_nocache/test_jf/Orange/Orange2/text360_m.png" style="position:absolute;"/>


    </div>
    <div id="Jeu_container">
    <img id="Jeu_played" class="Jeu" src="http://slpubmedias.tf1.fr/test_nocache/test_jf/Orange/Orange2/Jeu_m.jpg" style="visibility:hidden;position:absolute;"/>
    <iframe id="iframe" src="http://www.jeubignoel.com/"></iframe>
    </div>
    <a href="javascript:;" onClick="Bandeau(2);" ><img id="bandeau_bot" class="bandeau" src="http://slpubmedias.tf1.fr/test_nocache/test_jf/Orange/Orange2/Pub_bas_m.jpg" style="position:absolute;"/></a>
    <p id="mention2">
    Big = grand
    </p>
    <p id="mention">
   </p>

    <img id="track" src="http://slpubmedias.tf1.fr/test_nocache/test_jf/BlindSpot/Desktop/empty.png" style="position:absolute;">

    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Bitmovin Player](https://bitmovin.com/html5-player/) explicitly hid Chrome's native video element controls using CSS. Instead of hiding just the one of the used video element, it did this for all video elements on the website. This has been fixed in [version 7](https://bitmovin.com/bitmovin-html5-player-v7/) of the player, so you should not experience this problem anymore with the latest stable version.